# While parsing an XSD schema with XJCFacade . . . [ERROR] 'base' is already defined

Tags: jaxb, xsd, xjc

This error is very similar to "Property 'foo' is already defined.  However, please notice this error message does not state property.

```
[ERROR] 'base' is already defined
  line 8 of http://www.legislation.gov.uk/schemaModules/xml.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 114 of http://www.legislation.gov.uk/schemaModules/namespace.xsd

[ERROR] 'lang' is already defined
  line 9 of http://www.legislation.gov.uk/schemaModules/xml.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 94 of http://www.legislation.gov.uk/schemaModules/namespace.xsd

[ERROR] 'space' is already defined
  line 17 of http://www.legislation.gov.uk/schemaModules/xml.xsd

[ERROR] (related to above error) the first definition appears here
  line 105 of http://www.legislation.gov.uk/schemaModules/namespace.xsd
```

I am try to use XJCFacade to parse the schema at http://www.legislation.gov.uk/schema/legislation.xsd and create associated Java classes.  This schema imports another xsd file which in turns imports or references other xsd files including the two mentioned in the errors above.

Having seen similar problems before I have create and use a bindings file:

```
<bindings ...stuff removed because of SO restrictions . . .
  extenstionBindingsPrefixes="xjc"
      version="2.1">
<bindings schemaLocation="http://www.legislation.gov.uk/schemaModules/xml.xsd" node="/xs:schema">

    <!-- Customise the package name -->
    <schemaBindings>
        <package name="com.example.schema"/>
    </schemaBindings>

    <!-- rename the value element -->
        <bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='base']">
            <property name="baseAtt"/>
        </bindings>
        <bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='lang']">
            <property name="langAtt"/>
        </bindings>
    <bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='space']">
            <property name="spaceAtt"/>
        </bindings>
  </bindings>
</bindings>
```

It does read the file but otherwise ignores the the commands.  The file is definitely being read because is I purposely misspell one of the attributes in the bindings file it will tell me to object were found with that name.

Comment: Format the error messages as code to avoid the URL limit problem.

Comment: Thanks for the formatting hint.  All the URLs are back in.  Just need some help now the the puzzle . . .

Comment: What exactly is the question?  The schema documents you are processing include two different schema documents for the same namespace (specifically namespace `http://www.w3.org/XML/1998/namespace`); that leads to duplicate (and conflicting) declarations for the attributes xml:base, xml:lang, etc.